# How do I set logging to log in my timezone?

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to learn logging and I can't figure out how to set the output time as my localtime. Any idea?

```
import logging
import sys
import os
import time

path_to_log = os.path.abspath('path')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                              '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S%p')

console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log_file = logging.FileHandler(path_to_log)

console.setFormatter(formatter)
log_file.setFormatter(formatter)

console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_file.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console)
logger.addHandler(log_file)
```

Comment: I believe logging will use whatever timezone setting is present in the environment.  How are you running this code?  Are you running it directly from a script on the command line, or is it part of a web server application, or something else?

Comment: @JohnGordon you're right, the computer I was running it on had the wrong timezone. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

For that task you can change the `logging.Formatter.converter`.

```
logging.Formatter.converter = time.localtime
```

Then, to check if this worked

```
logger.error("ERROR")
```